# Computable models of ($\omega$, <) without computable isomorphism

Tags: computability

I read somewhere that "it is easy" to construct a computable presentation for the model ($\omega$, <) so that any computable isomorphism between this construction and the usual presentation of $\mathbb{N}$ (with the usual order) would compute the halting set.
So this would show that ($\omega$, <) is not computably categorical (clearly), but they didn't show the construction and I can't figure it out!

Does anyone know the construction?

Comment: You can obtain a proof by a minor variation of the argument described in the first part of the proof of Theorem 2.4 of Antonio Montalbán's [*Indecomposable linear orderings, and hyoerarithmetic analysis*](http://math.berkeley.edu/~antonio/papers/indec.pdf). (I saw Antonio give a talk a few years ago where he described this argument. In hindsight it is quite natural.)